# Update to esLint on Angular breaks commitlint

Tags: angular, git, eslint, commitizen

I just updated an Angular 11 app to eslint and installed commitizen, commitlint, husky and semantic-release to drive CI through npm and Travis.

I followed the instructions on the Angular recommended link.

Linting itself works fine.

The problem shows up in the commit-msg hook but is caused earlier.

Now when I run `npx git-cz` I get a different set of types for "type of commit".

I get Fix, Update, Breaking, Docs, Build, New, Upgrade.

Previously I got the Angular standard list "feat, fix, docs, style, refactor, perf, test, ci, chore, revert."

The commit-msg hook fails for two reasons:

1. `type must be lower-case`
2. `type must be one of [build, chore, ci, docs, feat, fix, perf, refactor, revert, style, test]`

I have spent several hours reading all the relevant docs but can't find how to change the list of types back to what it was.

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: Could this have something to do with it? https://github.com/commitizen/cz-conventional-changelog

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought but I couldn't find anything that would create that behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The problem only arose when I installed `cz-adapter-eslint`.

This adapter itself is based on `conventional-changelog-eslint` (https://github.com/conventional-changelog/conventional-changelog/tree/master/packages/conventional-changelog-eslint)

It is this changelog file which introduces the change from Angular commit messages to ESLint Convention commit message format.

The simple fix was to remove `cz-adapter-eslint`.

I will have to look at this further when I have time to find out the recommended adapters.